# Is it possible to prevent omission of aggregate initialization members?

Tags: c++, aggregate-initialization

I have a struct with many members of the same type, like this

```
struct VariablePointers {
   VariablePtr active;
   VariablePtr wasactive;
   VariablePtr filename;
};
```

The problem is that if I forget to initialize one of the struct members (e.g. `wasactive`), like this:

```
VariablePointers{activePtr, filename}
```

The compiler will not complain about it, but I will have one object that is partially initialized. How can I prevent this kind of error? I could add a constructor, but it would duplicate the list of variable twice, so I have to type all of this thrice!

Please also add **C++11** answers, if there's a solution for C++11 (currently I'm  restricted to that version). More recent language standards are welcome too, though!

Comment: Typing a constructor doesn't sound so terrible. Unless you have too many members, in which case, maybe refactoring is in order.

Comment: If you're supposed to initialize all members and forgot one, then the error makes sense and should be there to remind you that you need to initialize them all.

Comment: I read the question as: You want to enable `VariablePointers{activePtr, wasactivePtr,filename};` but at the same time `VariablePointers{activePtr, filename}` should be an error (it is a warning only), is this correct?

Comment: @Some but it is a warning only...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think he means the error is that you can accidentally omit an initializing value

Comment: To prevent such situations, you gotta use an array/vector!

Comment: @idclev463035818 Which is why one should always build with e.g. `-Werror` to turn them into errors. :)

Comment: @theWiseBro if you know how array/vector helps you should post an answer. Its not that obvious, I dont see it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But is it even a warning? Can't see it with VS2019.

Comment: Add a constructor.

Comment: There is a `-Wmissing-field-initializers` compilation flag.

Comment: @acraig5075 Unfortunately MSVC doesn't do it, or have an option to enable it (that I found). For GCC and Clang it's `-Wmissing-field-initializers` (which is included with `-Wextra`).

Comment: @Ron True, for *some* compilers. Not all.

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP did mention the constructor option and why they don't want to use it in the question.

Comment: @Ayxan So What?

Comment: I guess @Jesper wants me to wait for metaclasses https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/04/metaclasses-cpp-summary/ , right?

Comment: I was thinking that a union for the last member might help (idea being that default-initialization would go to a type where that is an error but a provided initializer goes to the desired type) but aggregate initialization only ever affects the first union member :(

Comment: Can we have a full example so we know what we're dealing with?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `-Werror` is usually a bad idea unless done very selectively. It’s OK enough to turn it on during development/CI, but never turn it on by default in a build. You’ll just make it a pain in the ass to use your project for everyone using slightly different setups where you might get warnings the devs didn’t see.

Comment: @Cubic Those build issues should then be reported to the developers in a perfect world.

Comment: @S.S. In a perfect world, you don't get build issues from developers confusing development and release to begin with.

Comment: @Cubic True. Well, maybe in a good workflow you get that.

Comment: Another simple way to achieve this is to not give the VariablePtr member type a no-arg constructor

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is a trick which triggers a linker error if a required initializer is missing:

```
struct init_required_t {
    template <class T>
    operator T() const; // Left undefined
} static const init_required;
```

Usage:

```
struct Foo {
    int bar = init_required;
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
}
```

Outcome:

```
/tmp/ccxwN7Pn.o: In function `Foo::Foo()':
prog.cc:(.text._ZN3FooC2Ev[_ZN3FooC5Ev]+0x12): undefined reference to `init_required_t::operator int<int>() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Caveats:

- Prior to C++14, this prevents `Foo` from being an aggregate at all.
- This technically relies on undefined behaviour (ODR violation), but should work on any sane platform.

Comment: You can delete the conversion operator and then it's a compiler error.

Comment: @jrok yes, but it is one as soon as `Foo` is declared, even if you never actually call the operator.

Comment: @jrok But then it does not compile even if the initialization is provided. https://godbolt.org/z/yHZNq_ **Addendum:** For MSVC it works as you described: https://godbolt.org/z/uQSvDa Is this a bug?

Comment: Thanks, this is nice! I think writing something invalid into the `operator T` template will move the error from link-time to compile-time? `static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "initialization required for this field").`

Comment: Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work with C++11, since it will become a non-aggregate then :( I removed the C++11 tag, so your answer is viable aswell (please don't delete it), but a C++11 solution is still preferred, if possible.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb my first stab was actually to trigger a compile-time error, but no matter what I did it would fully instantiate everything and error out as soon as `Foo` is declared (see discussion above). My bad for not noticing the C++11 tag.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I completely misunderstood the C++11 comment!

Comment: I think linker errors technically cause undefined behavior, don't they?

Comment: @S.S.Anne they are a result of ODR violations, which are UB indeed. Pragmatically, a linker which would silently ignore missing symbols would be pretty unusual.

Comment: @Quentin: I'd suggest listing the downside(s) right in the answer, for the benefit of future readers considering using this.  It looks like the least intrusive (other than compiler options or static analysis) and might be the least likely to hurt optimization (doesn't change the size at least)!  But making a non-aggregate might not be worth it for some use-cases and should be listed in the answer.

Comment: This trick is so cool, thank you ;)

Comment: Sadly, at least on MSVC, it doesn't seem to work with shared_ptr
https://godbolt.org/z/9MqjYfoa6

Comment: @Battlechicken thats... weird. It does work when changing the operator to `operator T&() const` though. I'm not sure why MSVC tries to convert to an intermediate type when a direct conversion exists.

Comment: @Quentin indeed, the T& addition seems to work!

Answer (score 23):

For clang and gcc you can compile with `-Werror=missing-field-initializers` that turns the warning on missing field initializers to an error. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/g_ZnLC)

**Edit:** For MSVC, there seems to be no warning emitted even at level `/Wall`, so I don't think it is possible to warn on missing initializers with this compiler. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E3fB99)

Answer (score 6):

Not an elegant and handy solution, I suppose... but should works also with C++11 and give a compile-time (not link-time) error.

The idea is to add in your struct an additional member, in the last position, of a type without default initialization (and that cannot initialize with a value of type `VariablePtr` (or whatever is the type of preceding values)

By example

```
struct bar
 {
   bar () = delete;

   template <typename T> 
   bar (T const &) = delete;

   bar (int) 
    { }
 };

struct foo
 {
   char a;
   char b;
   char c;

   bar sentinel;
 };
```

This way you're forced to add all elements in your aggregate initialization list, included the value to explicit initialize the last value (an integer for `sentinel`, in the example) or you get a "call to deleted constructor of 'bar'" error.

So

```
foo f1 {'a', 'b', 'c', 1};
```

compile and

```
foo f2 {'a', 'b'};  // ERROR
```

doesn't.

Unfortunately also

```
foo f3 {'a', 'b', 'c'};  // ERROR
```

doesn't compile.

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by MSalters (thanks) there is a defect (another defect) in my original example: a `bar` value could be initialized with a `char` value (that is convertible to `int`), so works the following initialization

```
foo f4 {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
```

and this can be highly confusing.

To avoid this problem, I've added the following deleted template constructor

```
 template <typename T> 
 bar (T const &) = delete;
```

so the preceding `f4` declaration gives a compilation error because the `d` value is intercepted by the template constructor that is deleted

Comment: Thanks, this is nice! It's not perfect as you mentioned, and also makes `foo f;` fail to compile, but maybe that's more of a feature than a flaw with this trick. Will accept if there's no better proposal than this.

Comment: I would make the bar constructor accept a const nested class member called something like init_list_end for readability

Comment: @GonenI - for readability you can accept an `enum`, and name `init_list_end` (o simply `list_end`) a value of that `enum`; but the readability add a lot of typewriting, so, given that the additional value is the weak point of this answer, I don't know if it's a good idea.

Comment: Maybe add something like `constexpr static int eol = 0;` in the header of `bar`. `test{a, b, c, eol}` seems pretty readable to me.

Comment: @n314159 - well... become `bar::eol`; it's almost as pass an `enum` value; but I don't think it's important: the core of the answer is "add in your struct an additional member, in last position, of a type without default initialization"; the `bar` part is just a trivial example to show that the solution works; the exact "type without default initialization" should depend from circumstances (IMHO).

Comment: For me, the chief problem with `bar(int)` is that `foo f4('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` compiles. @max66 suggests an `enum`, I'd suggest an `enum class`. The key is to avoid unintended conversions.

Comment: **Note that `bar` does take non-zero space in `foo` in at least some ABIs**, including x86-64 System V.  (https://godbolt.org/z/RvwZaK gcc9.2 -O3 -std=gnu++17).  If the members are `int`, it takes the size of an `int` (because size must be a multiple of alignment.)  So this can easily waste 8 bytes in a struct of 2 or 3 pointers.  `foo` is still trivially-copyable, though.  But still, the cure seems worse than the disease; especially if you can use a compiler that has warnings for this.  Interesting idea, but your answer should catalogue all the downsides.

Comment: @MSalters - This is a good point. Added a deleted constructor template to avoid it. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes: this is a defect (another); but, given the OP requirements, I suspect that there isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: I don't think so either.  (Other than `-Werror=missing-field-initializers`.  Part of establishing that is cataloguing the downsides in ideas, so people can consider whether making their program slower is worth it vs. just using a GCC option.  I think listing any/all downsides for something that implements a merely "nice to have" feature is totally reasonable and would improve the answer.  The fact that the downsides aren't limited to clunky source might totally rule it out for some use-cases.

Comment: I just realized that someone can now pass `NULL` by accident, which seems like a realistic risk around `VariablePtr`. I really think the sentinel should have a unique type.

Comment: This wouldn't work if you use designated initializers (which is a C++20 addition - though one which has enjoyed support from compilers for quite a while, being a part of the C99 standard), since then you could just initialize the sentinel, forgetting to initialize some member.

Comment: You can replace the sentinel's constructors with `explicit bar() {}`, so that it can only be initialized with an explicit `{}`, which should be quick to type and easy to distinguish visually.

Answer (score 4):

For [CppCoreCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers?view=vs-2019) there's a rule for checking exactly that, if all members have been initialized and that can be turned from warning into an error - that is usually program-wide of course.

Update:

The rule you want to check is part of typesafety `Type.6`:

> Type.6: Always initialize a member variable: always initialize,
>   possibly using default constructors or default member initializers.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is not to give the type of the members a no-arg constructor:

```
struct B
{
    B(int x) {}
};
struct A
{
    B a;
    B b;
    B c;
};

int main() {

        // A a1{ 1, 2 }; // will not compile 
        A a1{ 1, 2, 3 }; // will compile
```

Another option: If your members are const & , you have to initialize all of them:

```
struct A {    const int& x;    const int& y;    const int& z; };

int main() {

//A a1{ 1,2 };  // will not compile 
A a2{ 1,2, 3 }; // compiles OK
```

If you can live with one dummy const & member, you can combine that with @max66's idea of a sentinel.

```
struct end_of_init_list {};

struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    const end_of_init_list& dummy;
};

    int main() {

    //A a1{ 1,2 };  // will not compile
    //A a2{ 1,2, 3 }; // will not compile
    A a3{ 1,2, 3,end_of_init_list() }; // will compile
```

From cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of
>   members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members
>   are value-initialized. If a member of a reference type is one of these
>   remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

Another option is to take max66's sentinel idea and add some syntactic sugar for readability

```
struct init_list_guard
{
    struct ender {

    } static const end;
    init_list_guard() = delete;

    init_list_guard(ender e){ }
};

struct A
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;

    init_list_guard guard;
};

int main() {
   // A a1{ 1, 2 }; // will not compile 
   // A a2{ 1, init_list_guard::end }; // will not compile 
   A a3{ 1,2,3,init_list_guard::end }; // compiles OK
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes `A` unmovable and changes the copy-semantics (`A` is  not an aggregate of values anymore, so to speak) :(

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb OK. How about this idea in my edited answer?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: equally importantly, the first version adds a level of indirection by making the members pointers.  Even more importantly, they have to be a reference *to* something, and the `1,2,3` objects are effectively locals in automatic storage that go out of scope when the function ends.  And it makes the sizeof(A) 24 instead of 3 on a system with 64-bit pointers (like x86-64).

Comment: A dummy reference increases the size from 3 to 16 bytes (padding for alignment of the pointer (reference) member + the pointer itself.)  As long as you never use the reference, it's probably ok if it points to an object that's gone out of scope.  I'd certainly worry about it not optimizing away, and copying it around certainly won't.  (An empty class has a better chance of optimizing away other than its size, so the third option here is the least bad, but it still costs space in every object at least in some ABIs.  I'd still also worry about the padding hurting optimization in some cases.)